# mysql concatenate multiple existing tables into one new table

Tags: mysql

I've done some research but all of the examples that I've found seem too complicated given what I would like to do.  I have multiple tables of archived data by year (e.g. archive_2013, archive_2012, etc.) and would like to create a new master table (archive_master) consisting of all of the data from all of the tables.  The tables have no keys and only 2 columns, one varchar(120) and the other char(20).  I'm hoping that this is as simple and straightforward as I think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to create **one** new table?

You could use a simple INSERT INTO with a SELECT

See:

CREATE TABLE with SELECT

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

INSERT INTO TABLE with SELECT

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Example

You can create a new table:

```
create table 'xyz' select * from archive_2010;
insert into xyz select * from archive_2011;
```

Comment: your answer worked perfectly and was simple enough for this newbie to understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple UNION will do the trick:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM archive_2013
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2
FROM archive_2012
```

Combine it with an INSERT and you are done:

```
INSERT INTO full_archive
SELECT col1, col2
FROM archive_2013
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2
FROM archive_2012
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `archive_master` VALUES (SELECT * FROM `archive_2013`);